# Set device orientation depending on screen size

Tags: flutter

I have a Flutter app in which I need to set the device orientation, depending on the size of the device being used.

For example, if it is a mobile device, I'd like to set the orientation to portrait only. Anything larger than mobile and device can be freely rotated.

I'm aware of using `SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations`:

```
void main() async {
    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
         DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
         DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
    ]);
}
```

However because this needs to be set in the `main()` method, the `context` is not available. Therefore we cannot use `MediaQuery.of(context).size` to get the screen size and therefore determine if the device is a mobile device.

Is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **MediaQueryData.fromWindow**. You can use it to get the scren width.

```
main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  final double screenWidth = MediaQueryData.fromWindow(WidgetsBinding.instance.window).size.width;
  if (screenWidth < 500) {
    await SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.portraitUp, DeviceOrientation.portraitDown]);
  }

  runApp(MyApp());
}
```